# Ionic photo library does not load in iOS device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

We need to load photos from camera or library(photo-gallery) and upload it.
In Android device working fine but iOS has a below error:
TypeError: Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core**["cordova"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core**["cordova"])(this, "getPicture", { "callbackOrder": "reverse" }, arguments)', 'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core**["cordova"])' is an instance of Object)

Also, For more details see attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm05g.png)
Code:
if(sourceType=='library') {

```
        const Liboptions: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          sourceType:0,
          saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
          targetWidth:1024,
          targetHeight:720,
          allowEdit:true
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(Liboptions).then((imagePath) => {
        // Special handling for Android library

          var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
      });

    } else {

        const CamOptions: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          targetWidth:1024,
          targetHeight:720
        }
        //options.popoverOptions = CameraPopoverOption; options.correctOrientation = true;
        this.camera.getPicture(CamOptions).then((imagePath) => {
        // Special handling for Android library

          var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
      }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this line in your config file in ios platform

```
<config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
 <string>You can take photos</string>
</config-file>
```